Unable to Upgrade to Ubuntu 23 from 22.04.4 LTS
I want to Upgrade my Linux from 22.04.4 LTS to the latest version (23.10),As, I get the Pop Up to do so multiple time. But whenever I try to make upgrade each time the following errors occurs and the upgrade get cancelled.
Could you please help me out.
Failed to fetch http://mirrors.iitd.ac.in/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-wallpapers/ubuntu-wallpapers-mantic_23.10.4_all.deb Could not connect to 10.0.1.100:8090 (10.0.1.100), connection timed out

Failed to fetch http://mirrors.iitd.ac.in/ubuntu/pool/main/f/fonts-noto-cjk/fonts-noto-cjk_20230817%2brepack1-3_all.deb Unable to connect to 10.0.1.100:8090:

Failed to fetch http://10.0.1.100:8090/ips/block/fsize?pl=1&url=aHR0cDovL21pcnJvcnMuaWl0ZC5hYy5pbi91YnVudHUvcG9vbC9tYWluL2wvbGludXgtZmlybXdhcmUvbGludXgtZmlybXdhcmVfMjAyMzA5MTkuZ2l0MzY3MmNjYWItMHVidW50dTIuOV9hbWQ2NC5kZWI~ Unable to connect to 10.0.1.100:8090:

Failed to fetch http://mirrors.iitd.ac.in/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux/linux-modules-extra-6.5.0-26-generic_6.5.0-26.26_amd64.deb Unable to connect to 10.0.1.100:8090:

Failed to fetch http://mirrors.iitd.ac.in/ubuntu/pool/main/t/thunderbird/thunderbird_115.9.0%2bbuild1-0ubuntu0.23.10.1_amd64.deb Unable to connect to 10.0.1.100:8090:


@Terrance the upgrade path from 22.04 LTS to the next release (of the next cycle) is currently to 23.10; that is fully CI tested (even if it gets almost no QA as that occurs mostly for 22.04->22.10, 22.10->23.04 & 23.04->23.10)....   I see the issue as likely relating to local network as 10.0.1.100 is a local address but we're given few actual lines of the pasted output so I've little context & won't look far.

Regardless of the status of 23.xx Ubuntus, the far more "useful" upgrade is 24.04 as it is an LTS version.

Unable to connect to 10.0.1.100:8090 This is not an upgrade fault. This is a networking or proxy problem.

@karel The mentioned method is somewhat different of mine, Also, I have already done with the mentioned Answer but there is this same issue.

@Hannu I understand your concern but some of the Project is part of Different Linux Distribution which I have to test, that is why I have to make an upgrade.

@guiverc I have tried switching my Internet and also the server region for update delivery every time the same issue is there, Also, I would like to mention that the upgrade is suggested by the OS itself, and while the upgrade process is going on (During the Download) this happens.

The upgrade is supported; the Ubuntu Release Upgrader tool checks https://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release which shows from 22.04 the next upgrade is to 23.10 (Supported: 1) but that is not your issue (I believe).  Your local network (school? company?  or some controlled network) is not giving internet addresses to DNS queries but instead local addresses (10.0.1.100 in your message is a local address) thus your problem is [your local] network caused so I suggest providing details about your local LAN/network in your question

@AmanRanjan The answer that I  was referring to is the second answer that only got two upvotes.

@Aman can you open this in a webbrowser? https://mirrors.iitd.ac.in/ubuntu/pool/main/u/ubuntu-wallpapers/
